# Convert filename in a folder from upper case to lower case (Windows Command Prompt or PowerShell)

Tags: windows, vb.net, powershell, command, command-prompt

I have about 600 files in a folder that I need to convert form lower case to upper case.  I cannot install any apps in my machine since our IT won't allow it, hence, I either have to do it in powershell, CMD or maybe VB.

Example file:

dog_123.csv needs to be converted to DOG_123.csv

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really VB.NET? Not VBScript?

Answer (score 7):

In PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Basename.ToUpper() + $_.Extension }
```

or shorter:

```
ls | ren -n { $_.Basename.ToUpper() + $_.Extension }
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  Code/paste the code in PowerShell then point to the folder where you have your to be renamed file/s and run.  Works like a champ!

Answer (score 2):

In batch:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%n IN (*) DO ECHO "%%n"|FINDSTR /L "! ^" >nul&IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 SET "name=%%~nxn"
 SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
 FOR %%a IN (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
  ) DO SET "name=!name:%%a=%%a!"
 ECHO REN "%%~fn" "!name!"
 endlocal
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Note: will not rename names containing `!` or `^`. `REN` command merely `ECHO`ed. Remove the `ECHO` keyword before the `REN` to actually rename.

Comment: I save this script in notepad, then renamed it to a .bat file...Ran it inside the folder that has files to be renamed, but didn't work.

Comment: This only works for ASCII file names, though. And I guess you can use `||` instead of `&if errorlevel 1` which makes it a little easier on the eyes.

Comment: Smart and clever, indeed! However, for accuracy, I changed the line `ECHO REN ...` to `IF NOT ["%%~nxn"]==["!name!"] ECHO REN ...`

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each f In fso.GetFolder(".").Files
  f.Name = UCase(fso.GetBaseName(f)) & "." & fso.GetExtensionName(f) & "_"
  f.Name = Left(f.Name, Len(f.Name)-1)
Next
```

The file must be renamed to a temporary name first, because the `FileSystemObject` is case-insensitive and would otherwise complain that the file already exists.

Comment: Is there any way we could automate this and save it in a .vbs script and simply run it (double click) inside the folder with the files that are to be renamed?

Comment: Sure. Put the code from my updated answer into a .vbs file, copy it to your folder and double-click it there. Beware that this code has no safeguards for a situation where a file with the temporary name already exists!

Comment: Yes, it does. Press [F5] to refresh the folder view.